# Java writing dynamically to a String Array from InputStrem of a IOUtils, specifically copyBytes

Tags: java, arrays, hadoop, inputstream

Having read [the documentation from `copyBytes`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/IOUtils.html) (of `IOUtils`), we can see here it's parameters:

**copyBytes:**

```
public static void copyBytes(InputStream in,
                             OutputStream out,
                             int buffSize,
                             boolean close) throws IOException
```

Copies from one stream to another.

*Parameters:*

```
in - InputStrem to read from
out - OutputStream to write to
buffSize - the size of the buffer
close - whether or not close the InputStream and OutputStream at the end. The streams are closed in the finally clause.
```

*Throws:*

```
IOException
```

So, with this information in mind- I've got a data-structure like this:

```
List<String> inputLinesObject = IOUtils.readLines(in, "UTF-8");
```

^which is what I hope would be an extensible array list of strings, that I can populate with data from the file that I'm reading with that `copyBytes` method.

However, here's the code I use when I call the `copyBytes` method:

```
IOUtils.copyBytes(in, inputLinesObject, 4096, false);
```

That place where you see `inputLinesObject`, that's where I'd like to put my extensible array list that can collect that data and convert it to string format- but the way I'm doing it now is not the right way- and I'm somehow stuck- I can't see the right way to collect that data in the format of an array list of strings (*what is it at this point? As it comes from an* `inputSteam` *does that make it a* `byteArray`?).

Here's the full program- it reads in files from `HDFS` and -is supposed to (though currently is not) output them to an array list of strings- which finally will logged to the console with `System.out.println`.

```
// this concatenates output to terminal from hdfs 
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // supply this as input
    String uri = args[0];

    // reading in from hdfs
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);
    FSDataInputStream in = null;


    // create arraylist for hdfs file to flow into
    //List<String> inputLinesObject = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> inputLinesObject = IOUtils.readLines(in, "UTF-8");


    // TODO: how to make this go to a file rather than to the System.out?
    try
    {
        in = fs.open(new Path(uri));
        // The way:
        IOUtils.copyBytes(in, inputLinesObject, 4096, false);

    }
    finally{
        IOUtils.closeStream(in);
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `ByteArrayOutputStream`, see here:

```
    // supply this as input
    String uri = args[0];

    // reading in from hdfs
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);
    FSDataInputStream in = null;


    // create arraylist for hdfs file to flow into
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // Initialize List


    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    OutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(baos);


    try
    {

        in = fs.open(new Path(uri));
        // The way:
        IOUtils.copyBytes(in, os, 4096, false);

    }
    finally{
        IOUtils.closeStream(in);
    }

    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
    String dataAsString = new String(data, "UTF-8"); // or whatever encoding 

    System.out.println(dataAsString);
```